# When i resize my webpage the section expands vertically adding unwanted background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

[image]
When the webpage is on the big screen everything is perfect. All 3 blocks of text are inline and the white footer comes right after the background picture. 
But when I resize the window webpage automatically adds space after the picture.
 Not sure what I should do: have my picture repeated? But that won't look good. Leave it as it is? Not sure what to do? What is a good solution for this?

Comment: need you to add HTML for better understanding.

Comment: If you can share the relevant `html` and `css` it will give myself and others something to work with. Right now you leave the only option to assume what `css` is being used. If you can create a working example that would be fantastic but I think the solution would head towards using `CSS3` `@media` rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a background image, you can set the `background-size` to `cover` to ensure that it always covers the whole element.

See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/ut04htu0/

Comment: Good solution but notice the image will be stretched.

Comment: @NewToJS It shouldn't be stretched. It will be scaled but keep proportions. You can use it together with `background-position` to ensure that the center of the image is used. Eg: `background-position: center center;`

Comment: Take a looks at the image quality in the last example of your jsfiddle. You will notice the candy cane is much bigger than the rest and the quality is lost due to the image being stretched/scaled... or at least that's what I'm seeing in my browser -Google Chrome. either way, image quality is lost in your example hence my first comment but still a good answer.

Comment: Yes, it is due to scaling. I used a very low quality image to contain my example to the small box. Your image would also be scaled, but hopefully your image is higher quality to begin with. If it turns out to be a problem, you can add media queries to use a higher resolution depending on screen size. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: But also note that if you want the image to cover the whole background, you'll image will have to scale to do that. There is no way around that.

Answer (score 0):

If the background is an image(tag), through jquery set the height to window height in resize function.(jquery).

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $(".img").height($(window).height());
});
```

Here img is the class used for image tag. 
Hopefully this solves your problem